# Autoload doesn't locate previous packages

Tags: composer-php, installation, autoload, locate

I am learning to use composer and I am constantly stopping at one problem. I've tried to find the solution, without success...

When I install new packages into my vendor folder, where I already have packages installed, the new autoload.php + composer folder doesn't locate my previous packages anymore. However, my composer.lock still display all the packages.

Did I do something wrong? I used
`composer require package/name`
to add my new packages.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem solved:**

Autoload psr-4 wouldn't work.
After manually adding the code into autoload_psr4.php and autoload_classic.php everything works.

My issue also was that one of my packages didn't exist anymore (FormGuide/PHPFormValidator), which made that I couldn't simple re-install everything.